# найти число в массиве из конкретных символов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться. есть массив чисел [11,13]
которые были получены функцией N([3,1]) аргумент которой был обработан моим выражением и должен был найти меньшее число состоящее из этих самых цифр - 3 И 1!

как сделать что бы искало число из символом в аргументе функции N

Простым языком. Я хочу что бы имея допустим число 53 или 853 из всех чисел которые я отберу в массив , оно мне выбрало только то в котором присутствуют цифры 5 и 3 (35) и 8.5.3(358 и 538 и 385)а все остальные отбрасывало

Comment: Все-таки не очень понятно что на входе и что нужно получить на выходе...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function fn(arr, select) {
  return arr.filter(function(a) {
    return select.some(function(b) {
      return (a + '').split('').sort() + '' == (b + '').split('').sort() + ''
    })
  })
}
alert(fn([55, 567, 385, 583, 333], [853]));
alert(fn([11, 13], [31]));
```